# Why aren't my 303 redirects putting URLs into my browser history on Chrome?

Tags: http, google-chrome, firefox, redirect, back-button

I have the following set of resources:

`/random /1 /2 /3 /4 /5 /6`  (etc)

The /random is a HTTP 303 redirect (The "See Other" type, but the commonly abused 302 has the same results) that I have coded to choose a random URL and tell the browser to GET it. This works.

When on /1 and clicking on a link to GET /random, I do get redirected to one of the other URLS (say, /2)... then doing it again and say I get /3. Now /2 doesn't show up in the browser history on Chrome, though the HTTP_REFERRER header does point to /2. **Huh?**

Firefox works like I'd expect: repeating hits on /random ends up stuffing the history full of the other URLs, leaving a nice trail of everything I've seen.

But on Chrome, you can sit there and hit /random 50 times, seeing 50 URLs, ultimately, but one click on "go back" goes WAY back to before any randoms were hit.

It seems so unlikely that this is a bug in Chrome that I'm assuming I don't understand something fundamental, and am asking here.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I could be wrong about a bug:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2801